# passing cursor values into another function

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables, cursor

*i have a function which will delete the rows in the table for the given input id, the input is given to the function by another cursor_function.*

```
select * from t1;  
 id | col1    
----+-------  
  1 | user1  
  2 | user2  
  3 | user3  
  4 | user4  
  5 | user5   
(5 rows)  

create or replace function del_t1(int) returns void as $$  
declare  
a alias for $1;  
begin  
delete from t1 where id = a;  
return;  
end;  
$$language plpgsql;  


create or replace function del_cur(ref refcursor) returns void as $$  
declare   
a int;  
begin  
open ref scroll for select id from t1 where id > 3 order by id desc;  
fetch first from ref into a;  
perform del_t1(a);  
loop  
a := 0;  
fetch next from ref into a;  
perform del_t1(a);  
if (a=0) then  
exit;  
end if;  
end loop;  
end;  
$$ language plpgsql;
```

*when the function is executed,*

```
postgres# select del_cur('t1');
```

*it shows no error, no outputs, cursor just blinks, plz help me to solve this, this is small description of my big database tables, i need a cursor function which will pass its values one by one to another function.*

Comment: For a programmer it should go without saying that you provide the version number of your software. Which version of PostgreSQL do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the function `del_cur(refcursor)` is declared to take a cursor. But you never actually use it inside the function - the construct makes no sense at all.

What you are trying to do should be *much* easier with the [implicit cursor of a FOR loop](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION del_stuff()
 RETURNS void AS
$BODY$  
DECLARE   
    _a int;
BEGIN

FOR _a IN
    SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE id > 3 ORDER BY id DESC
LOOP
    DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id = _a;
    -- do other stuff?
END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I don't understand the need to delete the rows one by one in descending order. Are triggers involved? Maybe the whole thing can be as simple as:

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id > 3;
```

Comment: **Postgresql version is 9.1, i am using this function in tree structure tables, in which i need a function like this which will delete the child before deleting the parent.**

Comment: **the function which mention above was useful, i am not an expert in postgresql, just started to learn postgresql.. thanks..**

Comment: @MAHI: Yeah I get it, to much bold in my comment, sorry. It just would be so much easier if essential information was given to begin with. Cool that it works for you! :)